# Coordinates in Blend 4 Layouts?

Tags: layout, expression-blend, coordinates

I'm new to Blend 4 and I'm wondering why the Grid layout seems to have it's (0, 0) position in the lower-right corner instead of the upper-left corner ? Can I change it ? Because I want to set Rows/Cols height/width relative to the upper-left corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grid Panel's row/columns do pertain to the upper-left corner.  Here's a short tutorial on layout controls in Silverlight by Scott Gu:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-2-using-layout-management.aspx

Sometimes when working with Blend it will set crazy margins on controls which make them appear to be in different columns.  I would look at the xaml and ensure there's no other properties (margin, padding, transforms) that are making the control appear to be somewhere else in the layout.